# Putting a Meteor App on Site5?

Tags: meteor

I have a domain on http://site5.com and I will like to put a http://meteor.com app on it? How do you do it I have found no tutorials on it.

Thanks!

edit: It seems like this may not be a easy question to answer so is their any way to do it on more popular web hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bassed on yours edit.

The most easy way its deploying on Meteor servers.

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

or another good choose its [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com). [here its a good tutorial](http://devo.ps/blog/deploy-your-meteor-apps-on-digital-ocean-in-5-minutes/),the pricing its very low (like 5$ a month).

Another good Opcion will be [Modulus.io](https://modulus.io), they gave you 1 free month and they have a pretty nice detail tutorial [Modulus with MeteorJs](http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1647770-using-meteor-with-modulus)

There is also [Heorku](https://www.heroku.com) i never try this but i think they give you [750 free hours.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing)

About that [Site5 they support NodeJs](http://qa.site5.com/advanced/am-i-allowed-to-use-node-jsv8-on-a-shared-service/) so you can put up Meteor (i guess check **Answer# 2** On Forums)

So Good Luck

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful information!